# Programmatically auto-power on the phone

Tags: android

I would like to schedule a auto-power on when android is power off totally not stand-by. Why android does not start automatically when it starts charging or a charged battery is put?

Comment: Hmm, I seem to have an Android device which powers on when charger is connected (Sony Ericsson Xperia), but it feels more like a bug (it's supposed to go into an "off-but-charging" mode IMHO; maybe it's a CyanogenMod bug).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like scheduled a auto-power on when android is power off totally not stand-by.

This is not possible, except perhaps via custom hardware and firmware.

> Why android not start automatically when start to charging or put charged battery.

That is up to the device manufacturer. Some devices will start running automatically when you connect a charger, at least in some circumstances (e.g., Kindle Fire). You are welcome to build your own device with your own capabilities. This has nothing to do with the operating system, any more than Microsoft Windows determines whether or not a desktop PC will turn on when you plug in a power cord.