# Service does not work when the screen is off

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a function which is responsible for detecting my location along with the location of some records that I have in the realm of my database. I calculate a range of approximately 30 meters. If my location is close to the range, it will be saved as a record in another Realm class.

All good until there, but when the phone's screen is turned off, it stops working.

I don't know how to make it work, I need to keep recording while the screen is off. I use a timer in the service. I was investigating what WorkManager is, but I don't think that's what I need.

Can you help me how to improve my code?

Thank you!

```
class DistanceService : Service() {

private val timer = Timer()

override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
    Log.i("service", "Close DistanceService2")
    return null
}

override fun onCreate() {
    Log.i("service", "Iniciando DistanceService")
    super.onCreate()
}

private fun startService() {
    stopService(Intent(this, AlertRepartoSleepService::class.java))
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mainTask(), 0, 2000)
}

private inner class mainTask : TimerTask() {
    override fun run() {
        toastHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0)
    }
}

private val toastHandler = @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
object : Handler() {
    override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
        val gps = Gps(this@DistanceService)
        if (gps.isLocationEnabled()) {
            if (gps.latitude.toString() != "0.0" || gps.longitude.toString() != "0.0") {
                distance(this@DistanceService, gps.latitude.toString(), gps.longitude.toString())
                val toast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Rango SuministroReparto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, Gravity.CENTER, 0)
                toast.show()
            } else {
                Util.toastMensaje(applicationContext, "Gps Sin Cobertura")
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    timer.cancel()
    Log.i("service", "Close DistanceService")
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    startService()
    return START_STICKY
}

private fun distance(context: Context, latitud: String, longitud: String) {
    Completable.fromAction {
        Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { realm ->
            val suministroImp: SuministroImplementation = SuministroOver(realm)
            val registroImp: RegistroImplementation = RegistroOver(realm)

            val result: RealmResults<SuministroReparto>? = suministroImp.getSuministroReparto(1)
            if (result != null) {
                if (result.size != 0) {
                    for (r: SuministroReparto in result) {
                        if (r.latitud.isNotEmpty() && r.longitud.isNotEmpty()) {
                            val l1 = Location("location 1")
                            l1.latitude = r.latitud.toDouble()
                            l1.longitude = r.longitud.toDouble()
                            val l2 = Location("location 2")
                            l2.latitude = latitud.toDouble()
                            l2.longitude = longitud.toDouble()

                            try {
                                val distancia = calculationByDistance(l1, l2)
                                if (distancia <= 15) {
                                    if (r.foto_Reparto != 0) {
                                        val repartoId = registroImp.getRegistroIdentity()
                                        if (r.foto_Reparto != 2) {
                                            suministroImp.repartoSaveService(registroImp.getRegistroIdentity(), r.id_Reparto, r.id_Operario_Reparto, Util.getFechaActual(), latitud, longitud, r.id_observacion.toString(), 0)
                                        }
                                        context.startService(Intent(context, AlertRepartoSleepService::class.java)
                                                .putExtra("Cod_Orden_Reparto", r.Cod_Orden_Reparto)
                                                .putExtra("id_cab_Reparto", r.id_Reparto)
                                                .putExtra("direction", r.Direccion_Reparto)
                                                .putExtra("suministroNumeroReparto", r.Suministro_Numero_reparto)
                                                .putExtra("foto", r.foto_Reparto)
                                                .putExtra("operarioId", r.id_Operario_Reparto)
                                                .putExtra("cliente", r.Cliente_Reparto)
                                                .putExtra("registroId", repartoId))
                                        stopSelf()
                                        break
                                    } else {
                                        suministroImp.repartoSaveService(registroImp.getRegistroIdentity(), r.id_Reparto, r.id_Operario_Reparto, Util.getFechaActual(), latitud, longitud, r.id_observacion.toString(), 1)
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                Util.toastMensaje(applicationContext, e.toString())
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    notification(this@DistanceService)
                }
            }
        }
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(object : CompletableObserver {
                override fun onComplete() {
                    Log.i("TAG", "COMPLETADO")
                }

                override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {

                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    Log.i("TAG", e.toString())
                }
            })
}

private fun calculationByDistance(StartP: Location, EndP: Location): Double {
    val radius = 6371 * 1000
    val lat1 = StartP.latitude
    val lat2 = EndP.latitude
    val lon1 = StartP.longitude
    val lon2 = EndP.longitude
    val dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1)
    val dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1)
    val a = sin(dLat / 2) * sin(dLat / 2) + (cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
            * cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * sin(dLon / 2)
            * sin(dLon / 2))
    val c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
    val valueResult = radius * c
    val m = valueResult / 1
    val newFormat = DecimalFormat("####")
    val mInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(m))
    return mInDec.toDouble()
}

private fun getBasicNotificationBuilder(context: Context, channelId: String, playSound: Boolean)
        : NotificationCompat.Builder {
    val notificationSound: Uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
    val nBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(0)
    if (playSound) nBuilder.setSound(notificationSound)
    return nBuilder
}

private fun notification(context: Context) {
    val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    val nBuilder = getBasicNotificationBuilder(context, CHANNEL_ID_TIMER, false)
    nBuilder.setContentTitle(String.format("Reparto"))
            .setContentText("Acabas de culminar tus repartos . Tomar selfie FIN DE TRABAJO")
            .setVibrate(longArrayOf(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    val nManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    nManager.createNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID_TIMER, CHANNEL_NAME_TIMER, true)
    nManager.notify(1, nBuilder.build())
}

@TargetApi(26)
private fun NotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channelID: String,
                                                          channelName: String,
                                                          playSound: Boolean) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channelImportance = if (playSound) NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        else NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
        val nChannel = NotificationChannel(channelID, channelName, channelImportance)
        nChannel.enableLights(true)
        nChannel.lightColor = Color.BLUE
        this.createNotificationChannel(nChannel)
    }
}

companion object {
    private const val CHANNEL_ID_TIMER = "enable_gps"
    private const val CHANNEL_NAME_TIMER = "Dsige_Enable_Gps"
    private const val TIMER_ID = 0
}
}
```

Comment: Of course it's not running while phone is turned off. That's the point of turning off the phone. Android can't turn on the phone if that's what you're expecting. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674849/programmatically-auto-power-on-the-phone?rq=1

Comment: I mean when the screen is off it stops working. Not when the cell phone is off, it will obviously not work. Edit my post and I was more specific